# failure loading external css with document.write

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i'm having problem when i want to load css file with `document.write()` when i check in firebug i get message to

> reload the page to get source for common.css

i think that can be solve with reload page, but when i'm reload again the message is same..yeah because my code is like this...

```
var details = '';
    details += '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>';
    details += '<meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> ';
    details += '<link type="text/css" href="common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>';
    details += '<title>bla..bla..bla..</title>';
    details += '</head>';
    details += '<body>';
    details += '<div id="header">' + '<h1>' + "what do you want" + '</h1></div>';
    details += '<div id="content"></div>';
    details += '<div id="footer"></div>';
    details += '</body>';
    details += '</html>';
    document.open();
    document.write(details);
    document.close();
```

what wrong?
please tell me about this problem , thanks for your answer...

Comment: Why do you want to write documenttype, html, body tag with javascript? seems weird.. :)

Comment: that is in my case...too hard to explain why i want to create html tag with javascript. i think that is very important for me..because i have task on that code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load a css file with javascript I suggest you create a element and inject it instead of using document.write

```
    var css = document.createElement('link'); 
    css.type = 'text/css'; 
    css.src = 'common.css';
    var link = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]; 
    link.parentNode.insertBefore(css, link);
```